# Endpoint without port number

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

Is there any way to expose a microservice endpoint without port number in Azure Service Fabric? Port number can be defined in *ServiceManifest.xml* or it can be dynamically assigned by Service Fabric cluster, but how to call a service without specifying port number?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you do not have to specify port number if you do not need it. Service Fabric will automatically assign port to your service. I also do not define port number because we have 100+ services and it is "a little bit hard" to do that

Just omit Port declaration in ServiceManifest.xml

```
<Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="UserHttpEndpoint" Type="Input" />
      <Endpoint Protocol="tcp" Name="UserRpcEndpoint" Type="Input" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
```

Comment: I know that, but how should I call that endpoint URI by it's name instead of it's port? For example: http://example.com/UserHttpEndpoint/api/service instead of http://example.com:31002/api/service

Comment: Ok, you should implement api gateway for that. Use one of patterns:  Service registry, Client-side service discovery, Server-side service discovery

Comment: @Marko your question is: "Is there any way to expose a microservice endpoint without port number in Azure Service Fabric?"  So, the asnwer is: Yes, there is". You didn't mention about How to call service without port.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Question will be edited.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

An endpoint would be useless without a port. So even if you could have one, you shouldn't want it. You are probably looking for a way to call the service without knowing its port number. This can be achieved by using a [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy). With a reverse proxy you can call a service by providing the port of the reverse proxy.